# ASP.NET MVC launching time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a **big** **application** which I develop **(ASP.NET MVC)**, it wasn't initially mine and I received it from my client. **When I run it via Visual Studio, it takes about 2-3 minutes to launch**.

I'm wondering what is going on after pressing F5 button in VS (except copiling and copying dll's, views, content to output folder).

Comment: Have you tried multiple browsers?

Comment: Yes, I think it is not related to browsers

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess I'd say that you're compiling the cshtml code and that can be very slow in older versions of visual studio.
Check to see if you have

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

in your .csproj file.

see this answer
[MVC Application is extremely slow to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341345/mvc-application-is-extremely-slow-to-build)

Answer (score 1):

I believe every time you launch it from Visual Studio it creates new dll files, hence the waiting. But I could be wrong.