# ASP.NET MVC 5 applications really slow to build

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm getting into ASP.NET, and I'm using MVC 5 to build my applications while I follow some Pluralsight trainings. I noticed that in the video training the instructor's Visual Studio builds really fast, but in my computer, after I modify something, every time I build it usually takes from 90 to 120 seconds for the build to finish and I be able to navigate through my application on the browser.

My laptop isn't super old or slow, since it has a Core i5 with 4GB of RAM and an SSD. I've tried to [set the MvcBuildViews attribute to false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18063254/2534489), but still the problem persists. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Update 2.

Any ideas on what should be the problem?

Comment: 4GB of RAM is miniscule. You really should upgrade that.

Comment: One thing to note is that Visual Studio 2015 has had many complaints about performance, and there are some tips for speeding it up such as those [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31760339/181087) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31553560/181087). There is also an [official Microsoft document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/03/03/make-debugging-faster-with-visual-studio/) on speeding up debugging performance.

Comment: @mason I know it isn't much but it isn't exactly "minuscle", it's kind of a standard amount. But yeah, I have plans to upgrade it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it was a problem with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. Once I installed [Updated 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs) it got way faster to build. I noticed that now the IIS Express isn't closed between builds, so now when I build my MVC projects I usually see the result on the browser in less than 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Delete everything under 
C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSiteCache
Check here too
C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\siteName

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so long to give feedback, had some technical issues. I tried deleting both folders, but the problem persists. =/

Answer (score 0):

This is not much of an answer that will solve this problem for you. But, I specifically run into this issue with ASP.NET applications. With one of our solutions we have nearly 60 projects and that takes WAY to long to fully build and debug inside a browser from VS.

How I solved this was to point one of our servers with IIS to the folder that my presentation project builds too. This way when the web project is built I can browse my IIS website and see the changes. The downside to this is I can't actively debug in VS easily.

As far as speeding up VS to build this faster with debugging I have had no luck with my experience. From messing with symbol loads, just my code settings, VS IIS settings, but nothing has truly fixed this for me.