# Visual Studio takes a long time to build when using iText7

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, itext7

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC5 application wherein I need to create a PDF. I am using the iText7 nuget package to do so. The code works fine, however when I hit debug after making code changes, it takes a long time (close to 5 min) to build the solution. This doesn't happen if I manually clean or rebuild the solution/project. Why does this happen? Anyway to rectify/improve this?
Note:The build option is also set to "Always Build" on debug.

Comment: What is your VS version and project type?

Comment: Its VS2017 and MVC5 project .NET 4.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code works fine, however when I hit debug after making code
>   changes, it takes a long time (close to 5 min) to build the solution.
>   This doesn't happen if I manually clean or rebuild the
>   solution/project.

This issue may be related to some debugging integration tools, third-party extensions,cache files，etc. Please try my **suggestions** below:

**Suggestion**

**1)** disable option `Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General`.

If you use VS Enterprise, please disable `Enable IntelliTrace` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`IntelliTrace`-->`General`.

**2)** clean the component caches under `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxxx(15 is VS2017 and 16 is VS2019)\ComponentModelCache` and `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp`

**3)** disable any third party extensions under `Extensions and Updates` or use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start your VS

**4)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder,`bin`,`obj` folder under the physical path of the solution and then reopen your project.

**5)** try to add `<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>` in `xxxx.csproj` file. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341345/mvc-application-is-extremely-slow-to-build).

**6)** If your VS is not the latest version, please **update** it to the latest version in case there are some fixes.

**In addition**, you can set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Diagnostic/Detailed` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Projects and Solutions`-->`Build and Run` so that you can see the detailed build log on the output window and with it, you can see where the problem is.

Comment: I deleted the cache, deleted the hidden folders and updated the visual studio and now its fixed.